# How to code Jenkins pipeline to skip deploy and signal admins "config update required"?

Tags: jenkins

**Context Simple Jenkins CD**

I wrote a small app (spring boot) along with a Jenkins CD pipeline.

The (simple) declarative pipeline does the following:

- build
- unit tests
- integration tests
- deploy

Since spring boot generates a single artifact ("foo.jar" uber-jar), deployment simply "scp's" to the artifact to the production box (using jenkins ssh plugin).

The "ci/cd" setup presupposes that "production box" *already* has its config file. (e.g in spring boot, application.yml).

**The Wrinkle**

The setup works fine when the app does *not* require any configuration change.

However, if developers change code to require a  "configuration change" (e.g. add a new port, password, etc), I do *not* want to auto deploy.

(Nor do I want to update the servers configuration, i.e. slip in "port=8443" , without admins "actively knowing" the change.)

Instead, I want to "flag administrators", *"action required on your end"*, i.e. and have them actively add the config value (e.g. port or password) before deploying.

**Question**

- What's the Jenkins-native way to "tell" admins *"you must update your config before deploying new version of the application"* ?
- Any other recommendations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is here to automate your CI/CD, so the best approach would be to update the config file with another jenkins step or within the deploy step.

Now if you cannot automate this part, but we still want to be in an ideal world, a good practice is to deploy your artifact not to production but to a binary repository (Nexus or Artifactory) first. Then you could tell admins that the artifact is ready to be deployed.

The actual message you could send to admins could be an email or a slack with a template message that tells them that a new artifact is available and recall them how deployment must be proceed

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin